# What is the role of this procedure using Context_Info

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a procedure in our system that counts the number of users who have logged in the database:

```
declare @byt_MachineName varbinary(128)

set @byt_MachineName  = (cast(@byt_MachineName  as varbinary(128)))

set context_info @byt_MachineName

Select 'NumberOfLoggedAccess' = Count(*) From sys.sysprocesses With(Nolock)
Where context_info = @byt_MachineName Group By context_info
```

I Would like to know the internal mechanics, how does it work ? A step-by-step explanation would be very appreciate.

Thx for all.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125(v=sql.120).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fooa0b7b9f3-dbda-4350-a274-bd9ecd5c0a74.aspx

Comment: Yes, but they dont add very much, for me at least. Can you point something that iam missing ?